# how could I use 2 foreach in Laravel using 1 view

Tags: php, jquery, laravel

```html
<h2 class="section-subheading text-muted text-center">الكورس الاول</h2>
<div class="row text-center">

    @foreach ($data as $item)
    <div class="col-md-4 px-3">
        <div class="card shadow p-4">

            <h5 class="text-center">{{$item->name}}</h5>
            <hr>
            <a href="/lectures" class="btn btn-info">show lectures</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach

    <h2 class="section-subheading text-muted text-center">الكورس الثاني</h2>

    @foreach ($data2 as $item)
    <div class="col-md-4 px-3">
        <div class="card shadow p-4">

            <h5 class="text-center">{{$item->name}}</h5>
            <hr>
            <a href="/lectures" class="btn btn-info">show lectures</a>
        </div>
    </div>
    @endforeach
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your question correctly.

You can nest @foreach statements like so

```
@foreach ($list1 as $item1)
     ...
     @foreach ($list2 as $item2)
          ...
     @endforeach
     ...
@endforeach
```

You would obviously want to use better names for the variables than in my sample. You do not need to have additional statements between the loops. The "..." is there to show you can.

Answer (score 0):

```
@foreach ($data as $item)
     {{ $item->name }} 

     @foreach ($data2 as $item2)
          {{ $item2->name }} 
     @endforeach
     
@endforeach
```